# can't access ng-model from directive template

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to access a model which resides in template of directive. But directive's scope never displays that model. What wrong I'm doing ?

http://jsbin.com/xorujuqube/edit?html,js,console,output
[JSBIN-Reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what I was missing was , initializing an model from directive along with object & property variable ie. $scope.Obj.proper = true ;

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/facotegene/1/edit?html,js,console,output

couple of things, when you pass a variable from parent, you just use `of: "="` (this will create a 2-way binding between parent and directive). Second, `<test-d of="'test'"></test-d>` expects an angular variable ($scope or var attached to Ctrl). so you must use quotations like this if you just want to test it with a string.

Comment: Yes thats what I am doing in actual script but despite of that its not working.

Comment: you may also need to change your `template: <div ng-model=h>test</div>` to `<div ng-model=of>test</div>` as that is the name of your `scope` var